# Programatically press ALT+TAB until the active caption matches a given string in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to programmatically select a windows that matches a specific string in caption by pressing `ALT+TAB`.
Any idea how can I do that?

I'm trying to find an alternate solution to the code below which has a strange downside: the minimize button of the external application does not work unless I click twice the left mouse button on the taskbar where the rectangle of the form is. Notepad, Mozilla and other delphi application created by me do not display this behavior. The only program that is affected by this behavior is a commercial software that I'm trying to control by adding extra functions to it.

```
function FindWindowExtd(partialTitle: string): HWND;
var
  hWndTemp: hWnd;
  iLenText: Integer;
  cTitletemp: array [0..254] of Char;
  sTitleTemp: string;
begin
  hWndTemp := FindWindow(nil, nil);
  while hWndTemp <> 0 do begin
    iLenText := GetWindowText(hWndTemp, cTitletemp, 255);
    sTitleTemp := cTitletemp;
    sTitleTemp := UpperCase(copy( sTitleTemp, 1, iLenText));
    partialTitle := UpperCase(partialTitle);
    if pos( partialTitle, sTitleTemp ) <> 0 then
      Break;
    hWndTemp := GetWindow(hWndTemp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
  result := hWndTemp;
end;



 procedure Tform2.OnSchedule_1_Trigger(Sender: TScheduledEvent);
    var h:HWND;
        executabil:string;

    begin
    h:=FindWindowExtd(Edit_titlu_fereastra_program.text);
    if (h = 0) then
    begin
    // Oops not found
showmessage('THE WINDOW WAS NOT FOUND');

    end
    else
      begin
    // you got the handle!
    if iswindow(h) then begin

    showmessage('THE WINDOW WAS FOUND');
    ShowWindow(h,SW_MAXIMIZE);
    SetForegroundWindow(h);

      end;
      end;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't do it that way. Do it another way.

Comment: Do you mean like this: get the handle from the caption of the window and then do ShowWindow(h,SW_MAXIMIZE); SetForegroundWindow(h) ?

Comment: David is suggesting you edit your question to include the things you've tried. Code like in your comment is ideal, as that allows people to help tweak what you have, instead of try to start fresh.

Comment: As you say, the code you have shown seems to work for most applications, as it should.  Without more information about the target application it is probably not possible to answer this question.  If you cannot be certain that the application you are trying to control has already called `ShowWindow` itself at least once then this approach might not work.  `SW_SHOWNORMAL` or `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`, perhaps?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: format. add delphi-2010 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
procedure Keybd_Press   (const AKey : byte);
begin
  Keybd_Event (AKey,0,0,0);
end;

procedure Keybd_Release (const AKey : byte);
begin
  Keybd_Event (AKey,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
end;

Keybd_Press (VK_MENU);
Keybd_Press (VK_TAB);
Keybd_Release (VK_TAB);
Keybd_Release (VK_MENU);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `FindWindow` function from the Windows API to find the window with the desired caption and then bring that to front if you want.

Comment: I'm already using this approach in another project but it has a downside: the minimize button does not work correctly for all external applications. So I'm trying to overcome that by pressing ALT+TAB.

Comment: @user2858981 it would be helpful if you edit your original question to include the code you are using and the reasons that it does not do what you expect or would like.  You are more likely to get a helpful solution.  Right now you have incorrectly guessed at a solution and are asking us how to implement that incorrect solution.  Instead, describe the actual problem and we can help find the correct solution.

Comment: @user2858981 Do you mean FindWindow does not search among minimized windows or you cannot bring a minimized window to the front, or you want to also search those windows minimized to the system tray?

Comment: FindWindow works ok.The problem is that after i maximize the external application and press F5 inside it I can no longer minimize it unless I press twice the left mouse button on the taskbar in the place where the minimize form appears. I get the handle from the caption of the window and the i do ShowWindow(h,SW_MAXIMIZE); SetForegroundWindow(h);

Comment: @user2858981 Please update your question and also provide the code you are using to minimize the external application. Does that apply to all applications or a specific app requires that mouse trick?

Comment: @user2858981 You do know that you can call `ShowWindow(h,SW_MINIMIZE);` to actually minimize any window by its handle? Probably you haven't considered this because calling ShowWindow doesn't seem intuitive in such case because you actually want to hide the window by minimizing it. But blame Microsoft for doing this in such unintuitive way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info.I know that :-) My problem is that after taking control over the external application, the minimize button from the application does not work correctly for the pc user.I want to send commands to the app and the user to be able to use the app properly. My actions should not hinder the user in any way.